# How to delete all python software except what is needed by OS

Tags: python, macos, unix

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533298/macos-confused-by-pythons-what-can-i-do) SO post I outlined my problems, and I would like to try and solve them by getting rid of all my downloaded python launchers, modules, versions, pip etc (for python 2 & 3) and start afresh. My only problem is that macOS comes pre-loaded with python 2 and I don't think I can or should get rid of that, but I do have other versions of python 2 installed that I do want to delete.

Is there any help that you can offer that will tell me what to delete and what not to?

Should I need to use 'sudo' at all during my uninstalling?

Are there any tests to ensure certain things are completely gone?

Please keep answers fairly simple to understand implement.

When I reinstall the things I need, is it better to do it all via home-brew, then pip; instead of downloading from safari, unless necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed using `sudo` (or typed your password into an installer), you'll need this to uninstall too. Mac python is in `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/lib/python*`. Yes it can be good to install via homebrew, although I've had good success with the Anaconda distro of Python. The important thing is setting you `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` variables in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` so that it sees your custom installed Python before it sees the system install.